# How to use Push Notifications in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to implement push notification with webhook, so we know that GI created on top of SQL view will not support this, but will it support a projection DAC?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it supports projection DAC.

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica Framework monitors its cache. And in case if changes happened to be with usage of Acumatica cache, then Push Notifications will work.
But if you will make SQL and then make PXProjection, then cache of Acumatica still will not be used, hence GI will not be able to track notifications.

IMHO I'd suggest you to create multiple GI which are used for SQL view, and collect information for multiple tables via multiple GIs.

BTW, the same is true regarding PXDataBase.Update and PXDatabase.Insert and PXDataBase.Delete. If anywhere in the code one of these is used, then it will affect how cache of Acumatica will refresh and push notifications as well. Both of them are dependent of usage of cache.